# Attachment is not attached; rather it shows the contents in mail body using uuencode or mail command in mac osx

Tags: macos, shell, mailx, uuencode

I use the below command to attach a file.

```
mailx -s "Report 05/06/07" add@dom.com < /test_output/report.html

uuencode /test_output/report.html /test_output/report.html | mail -s "mailing my c file" add@dom.com
```

but the attachment is not attached with mail. The attachment content is shown in the mail body.

How i can solve this or is there any other way to send mail automatically with the attachment?

Comment: Embedding a binary into the body of the email does not make it an attachment. For that, you want to use MIME encoding. It's an established mechanism, two decades old, and is explained fairly well all over the Internet (a quick search with your favourite search engine will net many results). There's even [a super simple example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages) on Wikipedia. For easy handling of attachments from the command line, consider switching from mail/mailx to [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/), which is available in OSX via macports, fink, brew, etc.

Comment: thanks @ghoti i will follow your instruction.